# How to install objax with GPU support?

Tags: python, pip, jax

I have followed the objax documentation to install the library with GPU support: https://objax.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_setup.html

i.e.

`pip install --upgrade objax`

`CUDA_VERSION=11.6`

`` pip install -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html jaxlib==`python3 -c 'import jaxlib; print(jaxlib.__version__)'`+cuda`echo $CUDA_VERSION | sed s:\\\.::g` ``

However the last step doesn't work. I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.3.15+cuda116 (from versions: 0.1.32, 0.1.40, 0.1.41, 0.1.42, 0.1.43, 0.1.44, 0.1.46, 0.1.50, 0.1.51, 0.1.52, 0.1.55, 0.1.56, 0.1.57, 0.1.58, 0.1.59, 0.1.60, 0.1.61, 0.1.62, 0.1.63, 0.1.64, 0.1.65, 0.1.66, 0.1.67, 0.1.68, 0.1.69, 0.1.70, 0.1.71, 0.1.72, 0.1.73, 0.1.74, 0.1.75, 0.1.76, 0.3.0, 0.3.2, 0.3.5, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.10, 0.3.14, 0.3.15)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.3.15+cuda116

I have tried with multiple versions of python/CUDA, but I always get this error.

Executing `pip install --upgrade pip` at the begining does not help.

System description:

- Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- CUDA Version: 11.6
- Python version: 3.8.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX recently updated its GPU installation instructions, which you can find here: https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda

In particular, the CUDA wheels are now located at https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

So, for example, you can install JAX with

```
$ pip install "jax[cuda11_cudnn805]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

and replace `cuda11` and `cudnn805` respectively with the appropriate CUDA and CUDNN version for your system, ensuring that they match the versions listed in the index at the above URL.

I've sent a pull request to the objax repository to update the instructions you were following: https://github.com/google/objax/pull/246

Answer (score 0):

[The doc page](https://objax.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_setup.html) was [last updated](https://github.com/google/objax/blob/7fdc9e3d6c680cfc43ab45be70b46cd41dbc0f92/docs/source/installation_setup.rst) 2 year ago. It's outdated and due to this it currently  lies. Take a close look at https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html — there're currently no releases with CUDA.

As for no-CUDA versions you can install them directly from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/):

```
pip install jaxlib
```

For CUDA version — try to compile [from sources](https://github.com/google/jax/tree/main/jaxlib). Or use `conda`: https://anaconda.org/search?q=jaxlib